# Generate Random Numbers within several different parameters

Tags: java

I am getting a logic error every time I run this program, I feel like the code below should do exactly what the question wants, but the output is definitely wrong. I dont see what I am doing wrong.

Write a Java program (name it RandomNumbers) that generates random numbers as follows. Make sure to properly label your output for each part below and print the outputs on separate lines. As in the previous program, use the tab escape character to line-up the outputs after the labels.  a) A random integer number between 30 and 50 (inclusive).  b) A random integer number between 20 and -20 (inclusive).  c) A random integer number between -20 and -60 (inclusive).  d) A random floating-point number between 0.0 and 15.9999 (inclusive).

This is what I have so far:

```
public class RandomNumbers{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Part A) Generate a random integer number between 30 and 50 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): " +
            30 + (int)(Math.random() * ((50 - 30) + 1)));
    // Part B) Generate a random integer number between 20 and -20 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): " +
            (-20) + (int)(Math.random() * ((20 - (-20)) + 1)));
    // Part C) Generate a random integer number between -20 and -60 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): " +
            (-60) + (int)(Math.random() * (((-20) - (-60)) + 1)));
    // Part d) Generate a random floating-point number between 0.0 and 15.9999 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): " +
           0.0 + (double)(Math.random() * ((15.9999 - 0.0) + 1)));
}}
```

My output is: a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): 3018
a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): -207
a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): -6014
a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): 0.03.7171159220482286
which isnt right as you can see.

Comment: `I get errors` - it would be best if you showed us what you tried and what errors you got.

Comment: You could copy and paste your code and replace the parameters.

Comment: And another university assignment...

Comment: @RegularlyScheduledProgramming I'm not sure that's really a duplicate. The title indicates so but the OP actually asks for something totally different (how to do it for different sets of parameters).

Comment: Agreed. I've removed the duplicate comment. Austin ought to re-title the question.

Comment: Just a hint: generating random numbers in the range [-20...20] is pretty much the same as for the range [0...40]. Just subtract 20 from the result of the latter.

Comment: Tell your teacher tab is not an "escape character." Tab and escape are both control characters.

Comment: what is the difference between an escape and control character?

Comment: Consider posting an [MCVE]. All the printing examples are not needed for asking this question. One line such as `System.out.println("a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): " + 30 + (int)(Math.random() * ((50 - 30) + 1)));` is sufficient. In many case, doing so will not only get you better help faster, but will help you pin-point the problem, and in many cases solve it yourself.

Comment: What about debugging it ? And find out for yourself so you maybe understand why ? I Think this assignments are made to make you fail and figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you did not put your calculation in parenthesis.
Java will therefor consider the `+` signs in your expression as String concatenation.

Example:

```
System.out.println("Test"+1+2);
```

prints `Test12`, but

```
System.out.println("Test"+(1+2));
```

prints `Test3`.

So in your first example you will get `3018` as output because instead of adding 30+18 it simply adds both numbers to your String.

So the correct code that will give you your desired output will be

```
System.out.println("a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): " +
        (30 + (int)(Math.random() * ((50 - 30) + 1))));
```

Comment: You are correct, forgot the parentheses at the beginning of the computation. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Parentheses to the adding expressions, or it will be *concatenaded* instead of **added**. (Example: text + 30 + 1 => text301)
In the last case, you don't need to add 1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Part A) Generate a random integer number between 30 and 50 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between 30 and 50 (inclusive): " +
            (30 + (int)(Math.random() * ((50 - 30) + 1))) );
    // Part B) Generate a random integer number between 20 and -20 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between -20 and 20 (inclusive): " +
            ((-20) + (int)(Math.random() * ((20 - (-20)) + 1))) );
    // Part C) Generate a random integer number between -20 and -60 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between -20 and -60 (inclusive): " +
            ((-60) + (int)(Math.random() * (((-20) - (-60)) + 1))) );
    // Part d) Generate a random floating-point number between 0.0 and 15.9999 (inclusive)
    System.out.println("a) Random integer between 0.0 and 15.9999 (inclusive): " +
           (0.0 + (double)(Math.random() * (16)) );
}
```